# Der Genitiv von "Paket": "des Pakets" oder "des Paketes"?

Tags: genitive

Ich suche den korrekten Genitiv des Worts Paket (des Wortes Paket?)
Mir kommt "des Paketes" wie eine veraltete aber legale Form vor.  Ist das 'e' vor dem Genitiv-s eine aussterbende Gattung?

Comment: Beides ist richtig laut [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Paket) und [canoo.net](http://www.canoo.net/services/Controller?dispatch=inflection&input=Paket&features=%28Cat+N%29%28Gender+N%29&country=D&lookup=caseInSensitive) zeigt sogar noch die Dativ-Variante "Pakete". Canoo.net gibt zum THema [Genitiv Singular mit s oder es](http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-N/Texte/s-und-es-Gen.html) keine weitere Erklärung, ob veraltet oder nicht.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Nein, "des Paketes" ist nicht veraltet. Beide Formen sind richtig und auch üblich. Ich selbst verwende häufig den Genitiv mit -es, weil ich ihn leichter auszusprechen finde und mir einbilde, dass ich es durch die deutlichere Artikulation auch meinen Zuhörern leichter mache, mich zu verstehen.

Genau zu diesem Thema gibt's übrigens einen interessanten Duden-Beitrag:
http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/newsletter/duden-newsletter-vom-29-06-12

Comment: +1 für den interessanten Link.

Comment: Super. Danke für den Link.

Comment: Leider ist der Link inzwischen tot. Das Archiv geht nur bis 2014 zurück. Und die Wayback-Machine hat den Link leider auch nicht. Eventuell findet das noch jemand?

Comment: https://shop.duden.de/sprachwissen/newsletter/Duden-Newsletter-290612