# Genitiv von Fallnamen

Tags: genitive

Folgendes Beispiel ist mir unklar:

> Mit Hilfe des Genitiv/Genitivs...

Mein Regelwissen sagt "mit s",mein Sprachgefühl sagt "ohne s, is' älter und klingt klüger".
Im Internet finde ich Belege für beides.

- Was ist richtig?
- Wenn ohne s, dann warum?
- Klingt es ohne s nur für mich ok?

Edit:

Mag sein, dass "des Genitivs" deutlich häufiger gefunden wird. Im Falle des "Ablativ" sieht das aber anders aus... da gibt es für die Version mit s nur halb so viele Treffer wie für ohne.... [hier der Link](http://www.google.de/search?client=opera&q=%22des%20C%C3%A4sar%22&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest#channel=suggest&fp=a6dddd0bef92ed2b&psj=1&q=%22des%20ablativ%22) für ohne s

- Wie erklärt sich das?

Comment: Aber der Unterschied zwischen den Suchen von "des genitiv" und "des Genitivs" ist ja groß! (5k zu 24k)

Comment: Sprachgefühl: Eindeutig mit *-s*. Regel: Eindeutig mit *-s*. Corpora: Eindeutig mit *-s*

Comment: siehe auch http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/der-genitiv-von-paket-des-pakets-oder-des-paketes - dort ein netter Link zum Duden Newsletter

Comment: @c.p. : ich habe meine Frage editiert und als Beispiel den Ablativ reingenommen. Da ist die Suchergebnissituation umgekehrt. Ausserdem finde ich 5k zu 24k nicht grade beeindruckend. Jedes 5te Auftreten ist falsch? Ich glaube da kann man schon von Paralellverwendung reden

Comment: @c.p. Millionen Fliegen ...

Comment: @user unknown... Grammatik ist immer deskriptiv und beschreibt daher diese Fliegen

Answer (score 6):

It is simple. Because it is a masculine noun (nominative: *der* Genitiv), its ending in the genitive must be "s" or "es" (exception: weak masculine-n nouns as pointed out by chirlu in the comments below)

Note the following joke, because some dialects of German significantly reduce the use of the genitive case, or in some cases completely remove it:

> Der Dativ ist dem Genitiv sein Tod.

Compare with:

> Der Dativ ist der Tod des Genitivs.

As mentioned in comments above, it is pretty obvious that 'des Genitiv' is wrong.

Comment: I modified my question and I think it is not that simple any more.

Comment: Also, not all nouns of masculine gender have _-s_ (e.g., _Herr_).

Answer (score 4):

Quelle 1 -- [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Genitiv): `des Genitivs`

Quelle 2 -- [deutsches Wiktionary (basiert auf DWDS und Wortschatz der Uni Leipzig)](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Genitiv): `des Genitivs`

Ich würde mal ganz stark sagen, dass `des Genitivs` richtig ist.

Comment: ok... warum finden sich aber dann zahlreiche Belege für eine Verwendung "des Ablativ" auch in offenbar lektorierten Werken. Ich denke nicht, dass das einfach nur Fehler sind denn "des Auto" würde auch niemand einfach mal so schreiben. Meine Theorie ist, dass es etwas damit zu tun hat, dass bei Eigennamen eben kein s angehängt wird/wurde "die Antwort des Toscho"... und vielleicht werden seltene Fälle personifiziert wahrgenommen, der Name ist wirklich ein Name.

Comment: Deine Erklärung, dass seltene, entlehnte Fachwörter als Namen gedacht werden, passt doch sehr gut. Das heißt aber noch lange nicht, dass das richtig sei. Und ein lektoriertes Werk mit dieser Variante reicht als Argument nicht aus.

Answer (score 2):

Ich sehe das selber nicht als echte Antwort, aber für einen Kommentar war es zu lang:

Wahrig und Duden geben „des Ablativs“ an. Da wohl „Ablativ“ im Lateinischen kein Substantiv ist, sehe ich auch keine Rechtfertigung dafür, andere als deutsche Deklinationsregeln zu benutzen. Trotzdem kommen die Formen ohne „s“ auch [in neueren Texten](http://books.google.de/books?id=AKsDsH85vPoC&lpg=PA424&dq=%22des%20Genitiv%22&pg=PA424#v=onepage&q=%22des%20Genitiv%22&f=false) vor. Bei der Google-Suche muss man allerdings vorsichtig sein; was wie „des Ablativ“ aussieht, kann sich als „des Ablativ-irgendwas“ herausstellen. Besonders häufig ist „des Genitiv-s“.

Mit dieser Warnung: [Ablativ](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=des+Ablativ%2Cdes+Ablativs&year_start=1800&year_end=2020&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=), [Genitiv](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=des+Genitiv%2Cdes+Genitivs&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=).